# mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a form content like this:

```
<tr>
        <td>c.&nbsp;What is the poverty level of the clients that your institution aims to reach? (Check all that apply):</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="sfsd" value="fsdsdf" />Very poor clients<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sfsd" value="fsdsdf" />Poor clients<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sfsd" value="fsdsdf" />Low income clients<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sfsd" value="fsdsdf" />Not a specific focus/all population  
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mfi_name" class="text required" id="mfi_name" maxlength="30"/></td>
</tr>
```

now i have to make a table for inserting the answer of this question how can i do that in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need an entire table to harbor the result of just this question. If you were to create it, it would like like this...

```
form_id | answer
---------------
```

You could store the result in a VARCHAR or TEXT field, or store it an a field with an integer value and have a table to correlate a text value (for easier processing later).

What you may want is a table that stores the results of all the answers.

```
form_id | repsondent_name | response_1 | response_2
```

In phpMyAdmin, create a database if you do not already have one, and then create a new table by clicking on the database and filling in the create new table field. add columns corresponding to all your form fields. you may want to read up a bit on the field data types.

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldatatypes.php